# Should all event handlers added with on() be removed in the scope $destroy event handler

Tags: angularjs

Should I explicitly call `.off()` on all elements I added an event handler with `.on()` inside the `$destroy` handler, or any handlers added with `.on()` (vs. `.addEventListener()`) are automatically removed by Angular during `$destroy`?

**EDIT**:
The question is not a duplicate of the linked question.
I am not asking about listeners added using `jQuery`.

Thanks.

Comment: Please reopen, it's not a duplicate as I am not asking about listeners added using jQuery. jqLite is part of Angular and I don't think you have to remove them in the `$destroy` callback as that is done automatically by Angular for you.